# Angular How to delete photo from Recipe error Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to delete photo form my recipe and this is deleting the item but i have an error:
"Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined"
Photo is deleted but i can't see properly alert. To see effect i have to refresh page.
What i should do?

in my service:

```
deletePhoto(userId: number, recipeId: number, id: number) {
  return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + userId + '/recipes/' + recipeId + '/photos/' + id);
}
```

in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from 'src/app/_models/recipe';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipeService } from 'src/app/_services/recipe/recipe.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/_services/auth.service';
import { AlertifyService } from 'src/app/_services/alertify.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { RecipePhoto } from 'src/app/_models/recipePhoto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-edit',
  templateUrl: './recipe-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-edit.component.css']
})
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editForm', {static: true}) editForm: NgForm;
  recipe: Recipe;
  photos: RecipePhoto[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private recipeService: RecipeService, private authService: AuthService,
              private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.recipe = data.recipe;
    });
  }



  updateRecipe(id: number) {
    this.recipeService.editRecipe(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, id, this.recipe).subscribe(next => {
      this.alertify.success('Recipe updated successfully');
      this.editForm.reset(this.recipe);
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  deletePhoto(id: number) {
    this.alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this photo?', () => {
      this.recipeService.deletePhoto(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid, this.recipe.id, id).subscribe(() => {
        this.photos.splice(this.photos.findIndex(p => p.id === id), 1);
        this.alertify.success('Photo has been deleted');
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error('Failed to delete the photo');
      });
    });
  }

}
```

recipe-edit-component.html

```
  <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let photo of recipe.recipePhotos">
    <img src="{{photo.url}}" class="img-thumbnail p-1" alt="">
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
      (click)="deletePhoto(photo.id)" >
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Error says this.photos is undefined. Where are you defining / handling photos variable? You need an initialised variable photos in the component.

Comment: On the top of my component. I have just edited post.

Comment: So where does photos array get populated?

Comment: Array with photos is already partially filled.

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: I'm adding photos from asp.net core. I didn't write method for upload in angular yet. These photos are good i can display them in angular. This is just problem with splice.

Comment: The variable you declared -  photos: RecipePhoto[]; needs to be populated with the photos you return from the api. If you do this instead- photos: RecipePhoto[] = []; the splice error will go away because you have intialised the array. but there will be nothing to splice because the array is empty. What is the code where you retrieve the photos from the .net api? That must be where the fix is needed.

Comment: I understand. How should i make it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208705/discussion-between-jmp-and-bartolv9).

Comment: @BartolV9 : U need to populate `this.photos` before using `.splice` over it. SHare the entire component code please

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that photos is actually populated as part of recipe. If so, change:

```
 this.photos.splice(this.photos.findIndex(p => p.id === id), 1);
```

to

```
 this.recipe.photos.splice(this.recipe.photos.findIndex(p => p.id === id), 1);
```

Comment: Now i have ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined

Comment: oops, I've edited. Have another look. Have a close look and see what that line is doing and why the error happened too. hint - this.recipes.photos is a thing, (from your api) this.photos isn't. Appreciate if you mark as answered if this resolves it.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split it into two steps as follows,

```
let index = this.photos.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
this.photos = this.photos.splice(index , 1);
```

Comment: the same error :/ and when i used "let index" i got this message Identifier 'index' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)

Comment: try using arrow function

Comment: how this should look like? I'm beginner in angular.